# I need a script which can press a button and then type in it and then click another button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, console

Say I visit a website which has the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="enter">
<input type="submit" name="button">

<a id="confirm">Confirm</a>
```

I need a script which I can run in the Chrome console to press the `<a>` element then type the text 'hello' into the input field and then click submit. I need this process to repeat every minute.

I have tried using this code.. but it doesn't do anything.

```
window.setInterval(function() { 
   document.querySelector("#confirm").click();     
   document.querySelector(".enter").value = "Hello";     
   document.querySelector(".button").click(); 
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Are you looking to build a macro?

Comment: @Confiqure sorry, what's that?

Comment: I macro is an execution of tasks by the computer (example: first click here, then type a letter,  and finally click somewhere else). It's like a small set of instructions that you want the computer to be able to repeat

Comment: @Confiqure i suppose so yeah

Comment: You'd have better luck creating this type of script using a language that can you can use to take control of mouse and keyboard. I've done a number of macros using Java. Writing instructions on your website won't be of much use to you I don't think

Comment: Maybe because .click() is an event listener, not trigger

Comment: The first line should be fine but after you looking for ".enter" and ".button" classes but in your code enter and button are the *name* of the tags.
Add `class="enter"` and `class="button"` to the respective tags and everything should be work fine.

Comment: @DomenicoLuciani I'm not able to edit the html

Answer (score 0):

If the inputs are placed in a form try this, in this case if you need to access by the **name** and not the **class**:

```
window.setInterval(function() { 
  var form = document.forms[0];
  document.querySelector("#confirm").click();
  form.querySelector('input[name=enter]').value ="Hello";
  form.querySelector('input[name=button]').click(); 
}, 1000);
```

Otherwise your script above will work if the inputs have these correct **class** names

Comment: what if they're not in a form?

Answer (score -1):

Instead try using `trigger` as:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var event = JQuery.Event("click");
    $('#confirm').click(function() {
        $('.enter').value("Hello");
        $('.button').trigger(event);
    });
    $('#confirm').trigger(event);
});
```

Now just put the code inside your `window.setInterval()` function.

Comment: not exactly. `click()`, when you do not pass args is a shortcut for `trigger('click')`

Comment: That's wrong.  .click() method is just a shorthand for .on( "click", handler ). Source: https://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: try reading the entire sentence in the docs: "This method is a shortcut for .on( "click", handler ) in the first two variations, and .trigger( "click" ) in the third. ". In this case it's referencing the function call without args being a shortcut to `.trigger('click')`.

Comment: The difference between the two is that `.click()` just calls `.trigger('click')` under the hood. So you are saving a function call that most of the time does not matter in any case.

Comment: how do i use jquery in the chrome console

Comment: use CDN. Like: `var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js");`  @bobjomes

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: JQuery is not defined`

Comment: Make sure to use `$(document).ready(function() { } );` http://stackoverflow.com/a/2195167/5804813    I have also edited the answer for this